# How to bundle asset file with pure ESM NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules, drizzle

As the title of the question, I need to ship some assets with my ESM only module NPM package. The asssets in questions are some generated SQL files. I need to provide support in platform agnostic way.

I am authoring an ESM-only library having a folder containing SQL migration files generated by the ORM. I am using `drizzle-orm` to do the migrations and DB access. The `migrate` function provided by the `drizzle-orm` **expects the path to locate the migration files** and it is then supposed to read these migration files and apply them to the SQLite database (or, any database for that matter). The library exposes a custom `migrate` function on top this base `migrate` function.

Now, the library can be consumed in two different ways. In a traditional setup, it can be used by Node.js runtime and thus, the package will be available as is (with folder structure retained) in `node_modules` folder. But in case of server-less/edge platforms, the code will be bundled by the bundler like Webpack into a single file. So, this means, I cannot rely on relative path to resolve the folder name.

With CJS, it used to be a simple thing. I could simply use `require.resolve()` or `__dirname`/`__filename` to get the path of the folder. And, bundlers like Webpack, NCC, etc. rewrite these to proper paths at the time of bundling by doing static analysis (and, as long as the path is static string).

Unfortunately, with pure-ESM, I cannot use this technique. So, what's the way to provide the folder name as a string that can be used in these both situations?

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788717/is-there-a-module-system-agnostic-way-of-getting-the-path-of-the-current-file-in. However, you are using a bundler as well, and you should share more details about how you are bundling your app.