# Is there a module system-agnostic way of getting the path of the current file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

In node.js when using commonjs modules there are the very helpful `__dirname` and `__filename` magic variables. You can recreate these in ES modules easily enough:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname } from 'node:path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
```

The problem is that I work primarily on library code and we typically compile our Typescript library code to *both* commonly used module formats. Which means I can't do this:

```ts
import { dirname } from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'

function getCurrentDirname(): string {
    if (typeof __dirname === 'undefined') {
        return dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)));
    }

    return __dirname;
}

function getCurrentFilepath(): string {
    if (typeof __filename === 'undefined') {
        return fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
    }

    return __filename;
}
```

...as the parser will error as soon as it encounters the `import` when not in a ESM context. I can't even reliably hack my way around this limitation with a dynamic `eval` (setting aside for a moment all of the many problems with using `eval`):

```
import { dirname } from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'

function getCurrentDirname(): string {
    if (typeof __dirname === 'undefined') {
        return dirname(fileURLToPath(eval('import.meta.url')));
    }

    return __dirname;
}

function getCurrentFilepath(): string {
    if (typeof __filename === 'undefined') {
        return fileURLToPath(eval('import.meta.url'));
    }

    return __filename;
}
```

because that will fail to `eval` even if the file extension is `.mjs`!

Is there any module system-agnostic way to get the path of the current file that I can ship to both commonjs and ESM consumers?

Node 18 LTS if that matters. **UPDATE:** same issue in 20.x and 21.x.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. How come it's neither a commonjs module (where `__dirname` would exist) nor an es module (where the `eval('import.meta')` would work)?

Comment: @Bergi yeah that's the weird thing. I was under the impression that using the `.mjs` file extension forces evaluation of a file as an esmodule but this is apparently an edge case: putting that in a brand new `npm init`ed project as index.mjs and running `node index.mjs` will error: "SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module". Adding type: module in the package.json makes the error go away. I however cannot guarantee that my code won't be used e.g. in a `.mjs` configuration file or script in an otherwise CJS project though, so I can't just tell people to edit package.json.

Comment: That sounds like a bug, [nodejs documents esm being enabled by a `.mjs` file extension](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling). I'd suggest you make a mcve and [report an issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/new/choose). It sounds like it is treated as a script (with globals, i.e. neither a commonjs nor es module) but afaik this happens only for code in the repl.

Comment: @Bergi https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51424 thank you, any insight on this appreciated.

Comment: I guess it is not clear why you need the `eval` hack? You are saying that using an `.mjs` file without the `eval` hack will error when running within a CJS project? Because my answer would be use explicit file extensions to do it in a "module agnostic way".

Comment: Looks like you can execute an `.mjs` file from a CJS context without error on at least node 20.10.0. Check the [example](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel/compare/so-77788717?expand=1) and corresponding passing [test](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel/actions/runs/7476775943/job/20347956600). Is there a reason to use `eval`?

Comment: @morganney yes. I'm trying to write code that can be compiled from Typescript to *both* module formats. You *cannot* reference `import` in a CJS context because the file will fail to even parse. Using `eval` allows to *conditionally* reference `import` in a way that you cannot do with a normal conditional, because again the file won't even parse much less execute. BTW, love your `duel` tool.

Comment: @JaredSmith did you check out my example? Is that not executing an mjs file from a commonjs context? Wondering if I’m missing something as it is an interesting issue. I guess I should try from an empty project…

Comment: @JaredSmith Oops, my expectation about `eval` was wrong, using `import.meta` inside `eval`uated code is expected to be a syntax error according to the spec.